# Partial fraction decomposition of rational functions

Tags: partial-fractions, rational-functions

How can I start this with Partial fractions?

$$ \frac{10}{(s^2-4)(s^2+4)}+\frac{1}{s^2+4}$$

I was thinking of something like:

$$\frac{As^2+Bs+C}{s^2-4}+\frac{Ds^2+Es+F}{s^2+4}+\frac{Gs^2+Hs+O}{s^2-4} $$

But then it seems to fairly complicated.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can first work with $s^2$ as an atomic variable. Rewrite
$$ \frac{10}{(s^2-4)(s^2+4)}+\frac{1}{s^2+4}=\frac{s^2+6}{(s^2-4)(s^2+4)}.$$
Then two terms (hence two unknowns),
$$\frac A{s^2-4}+\frac B{s^2+4}$$
will suffice.
$$A+B=1\\4A-4B=6,$$
$$A=\frac54,B=-\frac14.$$
You can further decompose the quadratic denominators.

Comment: I know the answer is what you have, except there is also a 1/s^2+4 added. Where do you think that went in your solution?

Comment: Like I said, your solution is missing one term, so I am not sure if it's correct

Comment: Your remark is unclear. What is the expression to be decomposed and what is the expected solution ?

Comment: Nevermind, you are correct. thanks!

Comment: Can you always make t = s^2 substitution like that?

Comment: Not when there are odd powers, of course.

Comment: actually, its incorrect. answer should be:
$$\frac{9/4}{s^2-4}-\frac{5/4}{s^2+4}$$

Comment: Nope. Try $s=0$; the original expression equals $-10/16+1/4=-6/16$. Your answer gives $-9/16-5/16=-14/16$, mine gives $-5/16-1/16=-6/16$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $s^2-4=(s+2)(s-2)$ so you are looking for $$\frac {10}{(s^2-4)(s^2+4)}=\frac a{s+2}+\frac b{s-2}+\frac {cs+d}{s^2+4}$$to which you add $\cfrac 1{s^2+4}$ to get final term $\cfrac {cs+d+1}{s^2+4}$

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{10}{(s^2-4)(s^2+4)}+\frac{1}{s^2+4}=\frac{s^2+6}{(s^2-4)(s^2+4)}$$

Remember that $s^2-4=s^2-2^2=(s-2)(s+2)$

Then your partial fractions will be of the form $$\frac{Ax+B}{s^2+4}+\frac{C}{s+2}+\frac{D}{s-2}$$